# Вопрос о кнопках в C#

Tags: c#, button

Всем привет, хотел бы узнать,
у меня на форме 118 кнопок (Делаю таблицу Менделеева).
Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии каждой кнопки выводило новую форму с с картинкой и описанием?
Код перехода на след. форму я знаю

```
            Form1 form1 = new Form1(); 
            form1.Show();
```

а с остальным у меня проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть ответ запоздалый и уже неуместен, но всё же.
Насколько я понимаю, вся информация об элементах у Вас должна храниться где-то отдельно (БД, JSON, текстовый файл). Как идентифицировать кнопку, на которой произошло событие click, Вам уже [показал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1270966/182750) [aepot](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/373567). Во вторую форму Вам нужно просто передать информацию о периодическом элементе и её отобразить. Номер элемента Вы можете извлекать либо из текста кнопки; либо использовать свойство [Tag](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag), наследуемое от [Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control); либо создать специфичную кнопку, наследовав её от [Button](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button). Так как кнопок много, то на мой взгляд, добавление событий лучше автоматизировать, отказавшись от непосредственного добавления обработчиков в дизайнере.

**Примечание**

Принимая во внимание Ваши комментарии и [второй вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1270985), можно добавить, что т.к. один элемент может быть в разных [группах химических элементов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), то сохранение информации о принадлежности элемента к какой-либо группе лучше сохранять отдельно, а не напрямую в классе с ним ассоциирующимся, например, как Вам было [предложено](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1271166/182750) в массивах, либо списках и словарях (что Вам больше подходит). В этом случае, при выборе пользователем, например лантаноидов, можно просто "пробежать" по кнопкам и де/-активировать кнопки в зависимости от принадлежности к определённой группе:

```cs
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
  private readonly int[] _lanthanide =
  new int[] { 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71 };

  private void activateLanthanide()
  {
    // метод getControlsByType см. ниже
    foreach(var control in getControlsByType<PeriodicElementButton>(this))
    {
      // PeriodicElementButton см. ниже
      var button = (PeriodicElementButton)control;
      button.Enabled = _lanthanide.Contains(button.ElementNumber);
    }
  }
}
```

---

### Полный пример

Для начала создаём специфичную кнопку со свойством, которое будет хранить номер элемента:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ButtonExample
{
    public class PeriodicElementButton : Button
    {
        // Эти атрибуты указывают VisualStudio,
        // имя категории и имя свойства в визуальном редакторе.
        [Category("Periodic element info")]
        [DisplayName("Element number")]
        public int ElementNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Создаём класс, который будет представлять собой информацию о химическом элементе. Ниже приведены основные свойства и Вы можете расширять их по необходимости:

```cs
namespace ButtonExample
{
    public class PeriodicElementInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public double AtomicMass { get; set; }
        public int AtomicRadius { get; set; }
    }
}
```

В качестве хранилища информации выбран простой JSON-файл, находящийся в той-же директории, что и исполняемый файл. Опять-же, Вы можете хранить это и в базе данных, и в каком-то своём формате, но главное, чтоб Вы могли его прочитать и при необходимости изменить, добавляя и изменяя информацию об элементах:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "Name": "Водород",
    "AtomicMass": 1.008,
    "AtomicRadius": 53,
    "Designation": "H",
    "Description": "Водород..."
  },
  "2": {
    "Name": "Гелий",
    "AtomicMass": 4.002602,
    "AtomicRadius": 31,
    "Designation": "He",
    "Description": "Гелий..."
  },
  "3": {
    "Name": "Литий",
    "AtomicMass": 6.938,
    "AtomicRadius": 145,
    "Designation": "Li",
    "Description": "Литий..."
  }
}
```

Создаём форму, которая будет отображать информацию об элементе. Для этого, указываем зависимость в конструкторе формы от ранее созданного класса PeriodicElementInfo:

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ButtonExample
{
    public partial class PeriodicElementInfoForm : Form
    {
        private readonly PeriodicElementInfo _elementInfo;
        public PeriodicElementInfoForm(PeriodicElementInfo elementInfo)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _elementInfo = elementInfo
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(elementInfo));

            Load += onLoad;
            button_OK.Click += (_, _) => Close();
        }

        private void onLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Text = _elementInfo.Name;
            label_AtomicMass.Text = _elementInfo.AtomicMass.ToString();
            label_AtomicRadius.Text = _elementInfo.AtomicRadius.ToString();
            label_Designation.Text = _elementInfo.Designation;
            label_Description.Text = _elementInfo.Description;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь, главная форма.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ButtonExample
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        // словарь используется как хранилище информации об элементах
        private Dictionary<string, PeriodicElementInfo> _periodicElementInfos;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load += onLoad;
        }

        private void onLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // загружаем информацию об элементах
            _periodicElementInfos = loadElementsInfo();

            // Т.к. кнопок много, то обработчики события
            // добавляем автоматически в цикле, выбирая все контролы в форме по типу.
            var buttons = getControlsByType<PeriodicElementButton>(this);
            foreach(var button in buttons)
            {
                button.Click += periodicElementButton_Click;
            }
        }

        private void periodicElementButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = (PeriodicElementButton)sender;

            // Преобразуем в строку, т.к. "ключ" в JSON'е должен быть строкой
            string elementNumber = button.ElementNumber.ToString();

            // Получаем информацию из словаря, но в Вашем случае может быть
            // запрос к БД и т.д.
            PeriodicElementInfo elementInfo = _periodicElementInfos[elementNumber];

            // Передаём информацию форме и отображаем её как модальное окно.
            using var dlg = new PeriodicElementInfoForm(elementInfo);
            _ = dlg.ShowDialog(this);
        }

        // Простая десерилизация JSON-файла в словарь
        private static Dictionary<string, PeriodicElementInfo> loadElementsInfo()
        {
            string currentDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            const string JSON_NAME = "periodicElementsInfo.json";
            string jsonPath = Path.Combine(currentDir, JSON_NAME);
            // Смотри в приложенном архиве
            return NewtonsoftUtils.DeserializeFileContent<Dictionary<string, PeriodicElementInfo>>(jsonPath);
        }

        private IEnumerable<Control> getControlsByType<T>(Control parent) where T : class
        {
            var controls = parent.Controls.Cast<Control>();

            return controls
                .SelectMany(control => getControlsByType<T>(control))
                .Concat(controls)
                .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

[Весь код на GitHub'e](https://github.com/XelaNimed/PeriodicTableButtons).