# Как связать несколько кнопок, чтобы при нажатии одной нажимались все?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Вот моя программа, здесь при нажатии кнопки Группа 1, только кнопки вертикально от H до Fr должны быть доступны, а остальные кнопки в таблице должны быть заблокированы)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы эти кнопки руками в дизайнере расставили, или как-то сгенерировали?

Answer (score 0):

При инициализации формы нужно куда-нибудь поместить эту огромную кучу кнопок.
Самый простой вариант - в массивы со списками (предполагаю что батоны переделывать вам пока рано):

```
List<Button>[] HimGroups = new List<Button>[18]; //массив химических групп
Button h_He = new Button() { Text = "He" }; //предположим что это кнопка гелия
Button h_H = new Button() { Text = "H" }; //кнопка водорода
Button h_Li = new Button() { Text = "Li" }; //кнопка лития
//... итд...
//Далее заполняем списки:
HimGroups[0] = new List<Button>() { h_H, h_Li }; //добавляем H и Li в группу 1
HimGroups[17] = new List<Button>() { h_He }; //добавляем He группу 18
//итд... для остальных элементов
void selectHimGroup(int group) //пишем функцию выбора группы (-1 если нужно сбросить выбор)
{
    group--; //сдвиг, первая группа = 0й элемент массива
    if (group < 0 || group >= HimGroups.Length) //если группа не выбрана
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < HimGroups.Length; i++) //то проходим по всем кнопкам
        {
            HimGroups[i]?.ForEach(a => a.Enabled = true); //и активируем их
        }
    }
    else //если группа выбрана
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < HimGroups.Length; i++) //то проходим по всем кнопкам
        {
            HimGroups[i]?.ForEach(a => a.Enabled = (i == group)); //и активируем/деактивируем их по условию равенства
        }
    }
}
//далее эту функцию нужно вызывать из каждого нажатия на каждую группу:
private void ButtonGroup1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectHimGroup(1);
}
private void ButtonGroup2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    selectHimGroup(2);
}
//итд...
```

Слишком много вручную проделывать? Тогда для начала вам нужно разобраться как генерить кнопки или делать свои кнопки через наследование. Но это уже вопрос не по теме.